# In a integral domain, can every element be written as a product of primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a integral domain $D$, can every non-zero, non-unit element be written as a product of finite number of primes? Since an integral domain is just a generalization of the integers, I feel like this should be possible, but at the same time, things are not exactly so clear or even obvious in algebra so I am just not sure.

Note: an element $p$ is defined to be prime if it is nonzero, non unit and if p divides ab, then p divides a or p divides b.

Comment: Any element being a product of two primes is something which is not true even in $\mathbb{Z}$. If you mean a finite number of primes, this is still false in general, there are integral domains without prime factorization. See for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999158/is-there-an-integral-domain-containing-an-element-having-no-factorization-into-i

Comment: Yes I meant a finite number of primes. I will make a correction.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820328/700480

Comment: The same simple proof as in $\Bbb Z$ shows that if a nonzero nonunit  has a factorization into *primes* then that is *unique* in the sense that every other factorization into atoms (irreducibles) is the same (up to order and associates). So your hypothesis implies both existence *and* uniqueness of factorizations into atoms,  so the domain is a UFD - as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145061/242) in the dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.   Since a general $D$ is no longer necessarily the integers, you have to say what you mean by *prime*,  as well as the fact that $D$ might have its own different definition of *multiplication*.

Pretty clear that you're referring to the "fundamental theorem of arithmetic".

We do, I believe, have something pretty similar happening in the ring $D[x]$, of polynomials in the single variable $x$, which turns out to be an integral domain itself.

The analog of primes would be *irreducible polynomials*.   Those are polynomials that can't be factored into products of lower degree polynomials.

But, in general,  $D[x]$ need not be a UFD, or a *unique factorization domain*. Thus it won't always be possible to factor into irreducibles uniquely.

However,  if we start with a *field* $\Bbb F$, we do indeed get a UFD for $\Bbb F[x]$.

Turning it back down a notch,  I probably should have started with whether or not $D$ itself is a UFD.  Then, there's *prime ideals*,  which may be considered to sort of generalize the primes.

---

Suffice it to say that this story is only the beginning,  and that,  as you hinted,  algebra can be a very elaborate subject.   Enjoy your studies!

Comment: Isn't prime pretty well defined. an element p of a (commutative) ring is prime if p | ab implies p divides a or p divides b.  (in other words, p is prime if (p) is a prime ideal)